# Substituting multiple Strings in String

Tags: java, string, substitution

I know there are a lot of questions and answers related to similar questions but I couldn't find an answer to my question. This a small snippet of my code:

```
    private String substitute(String text) {
      List<Macro> macros = getMacros();

      for (Macro macro : macros) {
        text = StringUtils.replace(text, macro.getKey(), macro.getValue());
      }
      return text;
    }
```

1. Would this be a good way to substitute multiple macros variables in a text String? This creates a new String object on every loop so I am wondering if there's a better way to do this. Ideally I would have used Apache Commons `StrSubstitutor` class but I can't because of the format of the tokens/macros (different formats and not between a fixed prefix/suffix). I also don't want to use Regex because of performance issues.
2. According to some coding rules at work I need to mark the argument as `final`. I wonder if that's indeed good practice here. I know that Strings are immutable and I know that whenever I call `StringUtils.replace()` it will return me a new String object. But I am wondering if the String argument here should be marked as final as suggested and in the method do something like this:

   ```
   String result = text;
   for (Macro macro : macros) {
     result = StringUtils.replace(result, macro.getKey(), macro.getValue());
   }
   ```

   I just don't like this.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your concern seems to be valid. String is immutable so it creates multiple objects. You should you either use StringBuilder or StringBuffer.

I wrote a sample for you. Build from here

```
private static String substitute(String text) {
        List<Macro> macros = getMacros();
        StringBuffer st = new StringBuffer(text);

        for (Macro macro : macros) {
            int start = st.indexOf(macro.getKey());
            if (start != -1) {
                st.replace(start, start + macro.getKey().length(), macro.getValue());
            }
        }
        return st.toString();
    }
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use *apache velocity* to replace a string with keys with the equivalent string with values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some concerns about performance you could use a StringBuilder, which allows you to declare the text param as final:

```
private String substitute(final String text) {
    List<Macro> macros = getMacros();
    StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(text);
    for(Macro macro: macros) {
        int index=stringBuilder.indexOf(macro.getKey());
        if (index!=-1) {
            stringBuilder.replace(index, index+macro.getKey().length(), macro.getValue());
        }
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```